# Is there a way to hide a slash command from everyone except some users - discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created some commands which can only be used by specific users. I do not want those commands to show in the drop-down list of the slash commands for everyone.

How to hide those commands?

I am using discord.py v2, hybrid commands

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from utils.constants import owner_list

discord.http._set_api_version(9)

class owner_commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(name='sc', with_app_command=True)
    async def sc(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        # SENDS A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL USING THE CONTEXT OBJECT.
        if(str(ctx.message.author.id) in owner_list):
            embed = discord.Embed(title=str(len(self.bot.guilds))+" servers!", color=0xCC0066)
            
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

        else:
            await ctx.send("Command is not available")


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(owner_commands(bot))
    await bot.tree.sync()
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: No it' s not. You can only sync guilds or global.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the best you can do is implement a permission check and then refuse to execute it if some condition is not meant.

Comment: It is possible, you'll just have to do some shenanigans to make discord.py send some extra data along with the command. https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-permissions-object. I'll be back later with a working answer

Comment: I found a way to use permissions with app commands. But discord itself doesn't seem to have implemented them. If you want I can post the way to use permissions with discord.py as an answer, but it isn't really one.

Comment: @ParasolKirby Yes please, I would like to know how to use it

Comment: @DeadPool Well, but it doesn't even work right now, since discord hasn't implemented it...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do this on discord directly as the server owner.

go to server settings -> integrations -> click on your bot (manage)

Then in the "commands" tab select your command. There you can add roles, members or channels and set the permissions for them. Only users who have the permission to use the slash command will see it in the list of slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

See this discord support page: you need to do it within the discord server’s settings.
https://discord.com/blog/slash-commands-permissions-discord-apps-bots

(Server settings => integrations)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is that the slash commands are only usable for a specific group, for example admins. This is relatively easy to do:

1. Use the decorator `@app_commands.default_permissions()` with some permission. Example `@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_messages=True)`
2. Configure this permission according to some role. Example: You enable `manage_messages` for the `@staff` role.

**Result:** everyone with the @staff function can use the command, anyone else will not even see the command in the list.

**You can see the whitelist here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions**